# Dualbooting Windows 7 and Ubuntu on 2 hardisks

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 13.10, windows-7

I have an SSD with Windows 7 on it and a 1TB HDD with 200 GB storage to be accessed by Windows 7. I want to install Ubuntu on my HDD without erasing what I have on it. I have checked some videos but they show it on 1 hard disk and some people say to delete the partitions on the HDD to make partitions for Ubuntu.

Basically:

- Can I install Ubuntu on my second HDD without deleting what is on it
- Will I still be given a choice to dual boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 1 TB drive only has a 200 GB partition on it, skip the rest of this paragraph. If it has one big partition on the entire drive (w/200 GB data on it) it would be best to shrink that partition first using Window's own Disk Management tool. If you cannot shrink it enough, cancel, defrag it to move files down on it, then shrink it. You may need to reboot Windows for it to check the partition shrinkage, that all went well.

That should not lose any files on that drive, but it is best to back up what you definitely do not want to lose, in case you make a mistake or get interrupted (power failure, etc.)

Then you can install Ubuntu on the unallocated part of the 1 TB drive. Make sure that you know which drive is which. While you are booted from Ubuntu live/install you may want to run [bootinfo script](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) and look at RESULTS.txt to make sure you know which drive is which and that the Windows mbr is on the SSD. I will assume for the remainder that the SSD is your primary drive (/dev/sda) with Windows mbr, and 1 TB drive is /dev/sdb.

Not sure if automatic partitioning methods allow you to select where to pub grub, but I personally would select **Other** at the partitioning part of install, partition like I want it, and put grub on /dev/sdb (assuming 1 TB). Afterwards before rebooting, switch your BIOS to boot the 1 TB drive. From grub there you should be able to select whether to boot Linux or Windows.

I do something similar with the drives reversed, where I left Win7 and its mbr on my 1 TB drive /dev/sda, but boot using grub in the mbr of my SSD /dev/sdb (which contains Ubuntu).